# Shiny: how to plot several parameters on the same leaflet map?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, spatial

I'm new to shiny. I want to make a shiny app that shows the spatial distribution of different parameters. I used `meuse` dataset from `sp` package.

Here is the code I used

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
  titlePanel("Copper (ppm)"),
  leafletOutput("copper"),
  titlePanel("Lead (ppm)"),
  leafletOutput("lead"),
  titlePanel("Zinc (ppm)"),
  leafletOutput("zinc")
   )
  )
server <- function(input,output){
  output$copper <- renderLeaflet({

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- 1:2
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")                 
meuse <- spTransform(meuse, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
meuse_df <- as.data.frame(meuse)

leaflet(meuse_df) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap", group = "OpenStreetMap") %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~x, 
                   ~y, 
                   radius = ~copper/10,
                   stroke = FALSE, 
                   fillOpacity = 0.4, 
                   group = "meuse_df",
                   popup = ~as.character(copper)) %>%
addLayersControl(position = "bottomleft",
                 baseGroups = c("OpenStreetMap",
                            "Esri.WorldImagery"),
overlayGroups = "meuse_df")
})
  output$lead <- renderLeaflet({

  leaflet(meuse_df) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap", group = "OpenStreetMap") %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~x, 
                   ~y, 
                   radius = ~lead/50,
                   stroke = FALSE, 
                   fillOpacity = 0.4, 
                   group = "meuse_df",
                   popup = ~as.character(lead)) %>%
  addLayersControl(position = "bottomleft",
                   baseGroups = c("OpenStreetMap",
                                  "Esri.WorldImagery"),
                   overlayGroups = "meuse_df")
})

output$zinc <- renderLeaflet({

leaflet(meuse_df) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap", group = "OpenStreetMap") %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~x, 
                   ~y, 
                   radius = ~zinc/100,
                   stroke = FALSE, 
                   fillOpacity = 0.4, 
                   group = "meuse_df",
                   popup = ~as.character(zinc)) %>%
  addLayersControl(position = "bottomleft",
                   baseGroups = c("OpenStreetMap",
                                  "Esri.WorldImagery"),
                   overlayGroups = "meuse_df")
})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and here is the result I got

[image]

I wonder if there is a way to plot all parameters (copper, lead and zinc) on one map. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Symbolix's answer and suggestion of using `checkBoxGroupInput`. Instead, I used `addCircleMarkers` three times so I can plot all the metals on one map and I can switch them on and off

```
ui <- fluidPage(
mainPanel(
titlePanel("All metals (ppm)"),
leafletOutput("metals")
)
)
server <- function(input,output){
output$metals <- renderLeaflet({

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- 1:2
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")                 
meuse <- spTransform(meuse, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
meuse_df <- as.data.frame(meuse)

leaflet(meuse_df) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap", group = "OpenStreetMap") %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~x, 
                   ~y, 
                   radius = ~copper/10,
                   color ="red",
                   stroke = FALSE, 
                   fillOpacity = 0.4, 
                   group = "copper",
                   popup = ~as.character(copper)) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~x, 
                   ~y, 
                   radius = ~lead/50,
                   color ="gren",
                   stroke = FALSE, 
                   fillOpacity = 0.4, 
                   group = "lead",
                   popup = ~as.character(lead)) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~x, 
                   ~y, 
                   radius = ~zinc/100,
                   color ="blue",
                   stroke = FALSE, 
                   fillOpacity = 0.4, 
                   group = "zinc",
                   popup = ~as.character(zinc)) %>%
  addLayersControl(position = "bottomleft",
                   baseGroups = c("OpenStreetMap",
                                  "Esri.WorldImagery"),
                   overlayGroups = c("copper",
                                     "lead",
                                     "zinc"))
})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: How are you switching the markers on and off?

Comment: @Symbolix
I meant tick/untick the circle markers in the the addLayersControl in the bottom left of the final app

Comment: ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Melt your data so that your metals are in one column and you're good to go.

Here I use `library(reshape2)` to do the melt.

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(reshape2)

ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        titlePanel("Metals"),
        leafletOutput("all_metals")
    )
)
server <- function(input,output){

    output$all_metals <- renderLeaflet({

        data(meuse)
        coordinates(meuse) <- 1:2
        proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")                 
        meuse <- spTransform(meuse, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
        meuse_df <- as.data.frame(meuse)

        ## melt df so 'metals' are in one column
        ## using 'reshape2' library
        meuse_melt <- melt(meuse_df, measure.vars = c("copper","lead","zinc"), variable.name = "metal")

        ## specify factor levels for colours
        meuse_melt$metal <- factor(sample.int(5L, nrow(meuse_melt), TRUE))
        factpal <- colorFactor(topo.colors(5), meuse_melt$metal)

        ## now you just need one output
        leaflet(meuse_melt) %>% 
            addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap", group = "OpenStreetMap") %>% 
            addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery", group = "Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
            addCircleMarkers(~x, 
                             ~y, 
                             radius = ~value/100,
                             stroke = FALSE, 
                             fillOpacity = 0.4, 
                             group = "meuse_melt",
                             popup = ~metal,
                             color= ~factpal(metal)) %>%
            addLayersControl(position = "bottomleft",
                             baseGroups = c("OpenStreetMap", "Esri.WorldImagery"), overlayGroups = "meuse_melt") 
    })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time and help. Thanks to your answer, they can be plotted on the same map. However, they are on top of each other, so you can't click and get the values for each parameter (copper, lead and zinc). Is there away to be able to get the values for each parameter (e.g. cluster of circles at each location when you click at the location, it will show you the circles for the three parameters and you can get the value for each parameter by clicking the circle).

Comment: @aelwan - your update & subsequent question changes your original question quite a bit. It's not good practise to change your question once it's already been answered. Instead you should accept this answer (if it solves your original question), then ask a new question.

Comment: @aelwan no problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment above, thanks to your answer they can be plotted on the same map but I still can't get the values for each parameter when clicking on the circle because they are on top of each other. That's why I edited my question asking about another way of plotting other than the top of each other. I didn't mean to ask another question

Comment: @aelwan - Would a `checkBoxGroupInput` solve your issue, where you can select / de-select metals of interest so only the ones you want are displayed?

Answer (score 3):

To save you lines of code you could use **mapview** which provides multi-layer maps out of the box. If you only want certain attributes you can simply supply their names (or column numbers) to the 'zcol' argument. Alternatively, you can use 'burst = TRUE' to display all layers/columns present in the attribute table.

```
library(mapview)
library(sp)

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")                 
mapview(meuse, zcol = c("copper", "lead", "zinc"))  

## all layers
mapview(meuse, burst = TRUE)
```

mapview can be used with renderLeaflet.

Comment: Many thanks Tim for your concise, yet perfect answer.

Comment: You used the color to represent the different values for each parameter. Would it be possible to use the size (i.e. radius of the circle) as well here

Comment: Yes and no. You can map an attribute to the size/radius of the circles using the 'cex' attribute, but currently only one at a time. So you would need to layer you plot as follows to make this work for multiple layers.   

    `mapview(meuse, zcol = "copper", cex = "copper", col = "red") +`   
      `mapview(meuse, zcol = "lead", col = "blue") +`   
      `mapview(meuse, zcol = "zinc", col = "green")`

Comment: Thanks for your time and help